# String replaceAll method (Java)

Tags: java, string

I have following problem,

Code:

```
String a="Yeahh, I have no a idea what's happening now!";
System.out.println(a);
a=a.replaceAll("a", "");
System.out.println(a);
```

Before removing 'a', result:

> Yeahh, I have no a idea what's happening now!

Actual Result:
After removing 'a', result:

> Yehh, I hve no  ide wht's hppening now!

Desired Result:

> Yeahh, I have no idea what's happening now!

Anyone can give me some advices to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
a = a.replace(" a ", " ");
```

You don't need the `replaceAll(..)` method - it is if you want to use regex, and you don't need it, at least for this example.

If you need this for more complex examples than shown, then use `replaceAll(..)` and take a look at [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). For example, matching all whitespace characters is done using `\s`

Answer (score 2):

you should identify the particular "a" to remove
try this`a.replace(" a ", " ");`

Answer (score 1):

You were asking to replace every 'a', and that is what you got.

Some solutions:

- replaceAll(" a ", " ") (note the spaces around the 'a')
- use regex to chek for 'a' surrounded by word barriers (\b if I'm not mistaken)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

String str = "Yeahh, I have no a idea what's happening now!";

String newStr = str.replaceAll(" a ", " ");

Answer (score -2):

```
a.replace("Yeahh", "Yehh");
```

Is it just replacing the a in Yeah? or the first a in the string?

Comment: he wants to replace the "a" in "no a idea"